# Is this tawakkul?

Tags: tawakkul

I think I've done really badly in an important exam that I have to pass. I've been in this situation before and normallly I would be losing my mind right now.

However recently I've been trying to practice tawakkul, putting my trust in Allah and always having hope for a good outcome.

And even though I feel like I've done badly this time I can't help but feel really calm. It's quite strange.

Is this a sign of tawakkul? A sign that everything will be okay?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Your post doesn't include any hint about what you mean to refer to as tawwakul, what exactly have you done and what not? Please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. *Tawakkul* will free and ease your mind, as you are accepting both the *qadha’* and *qadar*, and that everything happens because of a certain reason.

The true meaning of *Tawakkul* includes determination, resolve, strategy, great effort, supplication and lastly, **contentment with the decision of Allah SWT**. Consequently, if it fails, you will be patient and putting trust to Allah SWT. Surely, there are hidden wisdoms that transcend human minds.

Wallahualam.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very important basic question.

On the one hand we must admit that we are actually small and we cannot change the world according to our own will but everything is submitted to the Will and the Rules of God.

On the other hand we are in mid of all we are able to do, and an active part of all that happens through the Will or through the Principle of God.

All your effort is on your side but the yield of the effort is on God's side.

So., God cannot increase your knowledge unless you learn properly. So you have to learn properly to succeed.

God will always be on your side if you seek to be a servant of Him. If you are on His path, He will guide you.

So what is the answer?

Yes, tawakkul is always right:

If you learn and prepare and do all according to His will, He will guide you through this way.

If you don't learn and prepare, but stay firm to His path, you will fail but He will continue to guide your on an other way.

If you are not in agreement with the Will of God,

you may succeed in the examination but not succeed to beuseful in your life and happy in your afterlife.

you may not succeed in the examination and not succeed to be useful in your life and happy in your afterlife.